# Unit testing Angular2 component template with sortby pipe

Tags: angular, unit-testing, sorting, pipe, karma-runner

I have a component that contains an ngFor loop in it's template. I'm using an order by pipe called 'ngx-order-pipe' in order to be able to sort my objects by a property called 'orderNum'. The sorting works perfectly when I run it but I'm having difficulty unit testing this.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let group of fieldGroups | orderBy : orderNumber">
    <div id="field-groups">
        <h3>{{ group.groupName }}</h3>
        <app-dt-field-render [fields]="group.fields"></app-dt-field-render>
    </div>
    <hr>
</ng-container>
```

My component is simple and simply has an input field that accepts an array.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FieldGroup } from '../../../models/dynamic-template/render';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-dt-field-group-render',
  templateUrl: 'field-group-render.component.html'
})

export class FieldGroupRenderComponent {

  @Input() fieldGroups: FieldGroup[];

  constructor() { }

}
```

I've attempted to unit test this by creating 2 objects in my array and adding them in reverse sort order. I would expect that my template output would have my objects sorted correctly. Here is the test:

```
it('should order primitive fields but does not for some reason', () => {
    testPrimitiveField = new PrimitiveField();
    testPrimitiveField.dataType = 1;
    testPrimitiveField.fieldType = 0;
    testPrimitiveField.orderNum = 2;
    testPrimitiveField.fieldName = 'two';

    testSecondPrimitiveField = new PrimitiveField();
    testSecondPrimitiveField.dataType = 1;
    testSecondPrimitiveField.fieldType = 0;
    testSecondPrimitiveField.orderNum = 1;
    testSecondPrimitiveField.fieldName = 'one';

    fixture.componentInstance.fields.push(testPrimitiveField, testSecondPrimitiveField);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    const output = compiled.querySelector('#dynamic-fields');
    const elements = output.getElementsByTagName('app-dt-primitive-text-render');

    expect(output.childElementCount).toEqual(2);
    expect(elements.length).toEqual(2);

    // This should be object with OrderNum == 1 but it isn't
    console.log(fixture.componentInstance.fields[0])
    console.log(output.firstElementChild)

    // This should be object with OrderNum == 2 but it isn't
    console.log(fixture.componentInstance.fields[1])
    console.log(output.lastElementChild)
});
```

Neither my output nor my array are being sorted. I suspect it has something to do with the pipe either not being injected into my test or that I have some sort of async issue. Any advice or direction is appreciated.